Оставить в списке только строки, заканчивающиеся на .html
Код должен выводить только строки с ".html" в конце
Вот код:
input_str = list(input("Введите строки: ").split())
html_end = ".html"
html_str = 0
    
for i in range(len(input_str)):
    if input_str[i].endswith(html_end):
        html_str += 1
    else:
        html_str = 0
    
print(input_str)

А выводит вот так:

Введите строки: python.html pascal java.html

['python.html', 'pascal', 'java.html']

Подскажите, в чём проблема?

Ну так вы выводите исходный список :) а в цикле просто считаете количество найденного(и там кстати else не нужно, оно вам будет занулять переменную при каждом не вхождении.

Судя по вопросу, вы не только не знаете про существование знаков препинания, вы еще совершенно не понимаете, что делает ваш же код.

HTML_END = ".html" # объявляем константу

input_string = list(input("Введите строки: ").split()) # считываем строку

need_items = [item for item in input_string if item.endswith(HTML_END)]
# оставляем только нужные
print(*need_items) # выводим нужные на экран


Входные данные: 
python.html pascal java.html
Выходные данные: 
python.html java.html
